# Export Postgres table as json

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, json, export, dump

Is there a way to export postgres table data as json to a file? I need the output to be line by line, like:

```
{'id':1,'name':'David'}
{'id':2,'name':'James'}
...
```

EDIT: postgres version: 9.3.4

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try [here](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql) for a basic intro to `PostgreSQL` and `JSON`.

Also, PostgreSQL documentation is pretty good, so try it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html). Check out the `pretty_bool` option.

Your original question was "Is there a way to export postgres table data as `JSON`". You wanted it in this format

```
{'id':1,'name':'David'}
{'id':2,'name':'James'}
...
```

I didn't have a running instance of `PostgreSQL` so I downloaded, compiled and installed 9.4.

To answer this, I first `CREATE`ed a table (fred)

```
CREATE TABLE fred (mary INT, jimmy INT, paulie VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO fred VALUES (2,    43, 'asfasfasfd'      );
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (3,   435, 'ererere'         );
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (6, 43343, 'eresdfssfsfasfae');
```

Then, to check:

```
test=# select * from fred;

 mary | jimmy |      paulie      
------+-------+------------------
    2 |    43 | asfasfasfd
    3 |   435 | ererere
    6 | 43343 | eresdfssfsfasfae
```

Then I issued this command

```
test=# COPY (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t) 
test(# FROM (SELECT * FROM fred) t) 
test-# TO '/paulstuff/sware/db/postgres/inst/myfile';
COPY 3
test=#
```

I then quit psql and listed the file myfile.

```
test=# \q
[pol@polhost inst]$ more myfile 
{"mary":2,"jimmy":43,"paulie":"asfasfasfd"}
{"mary":3,"jimmy":435,"paulie":"ererere"}
{"mary":6,"jimmy":43343,"paulie":"eresdfssfsfasfae"}
[pol@polhost inst]$
```

(you can experiment with the output from

```
COPY (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t, TRUE)  -- <-- Note addition of "TRUE" here!
```

at your leisure).

It was pointed out by @offby1 that the output (while corresponding to the OP's question) is not correct `JSON`. @EvanCarroll pointed out that `\o` is also a way of outputting to a file, so I combined the solutions to these two niggles in this statement (with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006432/470530)):

```
test=# \o out.json
test=# SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(fred), FALSE) AS ok_json FROM fred;
                                     -- <-- "TRUE" here will produce plus
                                        ("+) signs in the output. "FALSE"
                                        is the default anyway.
test=# \o
```

gives:

```
[pol@polhost inst]$ more out.json 
                                                                   ok_json                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"mary":2,"jimmy":43,"paulie":"asfasfasfd"},{"mary":3,"jimmy":435,"paulie":"ererere"},{"mary":6,"jimmy":43343,"paulie":"eresdfssfsfasfae"}]
(1 row)
[pol@polhost inst]$
```

**FINALLY**, there is the backslash (`\`) problem alluded to by @AdamGent in his post. This was a bit tricky, but it **is** possible without resorting to post-query processing. Voilà:

```
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (35, 5, 'wrew\sdfsd');
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (3, 44545, '\sdfs\\\sfs\\gf');
```

And using REGEXP_REPLACE thus (note the cast ::TEXT) removes the excess blackslashes.

```
test=# \o slash.json
test=# SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ROW_TO_JSON(t)::TEXT, '\\\\', '\\', 'g') 
test=# FROM (SELECT * FROM fred) AS t;  -- I found that using a CTE was helpful for legibility
test=# \o
test=# \q
```

gives:

```
[pol@polhost inst]$ more slash.json 
                    regexp_replace                    
------------------------------------------------------
 {"mary":2,"jimmy":43,"paulie":"asfasfasfd"}
 {"mary":3,"jimmy":435,"paulie":"ererere"}
 {"mary":6,"jimmy":43343,"paulie":"eresdfssfsfasfae"}
 {"mary":35,"jimmy":5,"paulie":"wrew\sdfsd"}
 {"mary":3,"jimmy":44545,"paulie":"\sdfs\\\sfs\\gf"}
(5 rows)
[pol@polhost inst]$
```

(p.s. As for @Zoltán 's comment - this may be a version thing - unable to reproduce!).

Comment: That seems to be exactly what the original poster wanted.  Note, however, that while each _row_ is proper JSON, the _collection_ of rows isn't, since it lacks commas separating the rows, and square brackets surrounding them.

Comment: This will **NOT** work if you have any `backslash` in your columns!!!! Read carefully the COPY doc as it does special things for `backslash` characters (like adding another backslash).

Comment: READ @AdamGent 's answer below to solve the backslash issue

Comment: @offby1 - take a look at my revised answer which I believe answers your issue!

Comment: @AdamGent - take a look at the use of `REGEXP_REPLACE` which obviates your issue!

Comment: So... year 2017 and **NO WAY TO EXPORT JSON** with COPY command PostgreSQL??  There are CSV option, TXT option... Why not an JSON option?

Comment: I **think** that if you try `COPY` with `SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(table_name)` - that should give "proper" JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Vérace. And sorry, now I tested a COPY with complex JSONb and the proceded JSON was fine, "proper JSON"!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote me! :-)

Comment: @Vérace thank you such for this detailed answer. +1

Answer (score 39):

If you're using `psql` then there is no reason to use `\COPY` at all.

```
\t
\a
\o file.json
SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM my_table AS r;
```

This is the same method we use to get png/jpgs/tifs out of the database with PostGIS for quick tests, and also to generate script files with PostgreSQL extensions.

Comment: Great! As usual COPY command *"not allow relative path"*, the `psql`-native-commands is the **easiest way to copy into relative path**! PS: there are a "terminal way" to use real COPY command with relative path, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464864/287948). `psql -h remotehost -d remote_mydb -U myuser -c  "COPY (SELECT '{\"x\":1,\"y\":[\"a\",2]}'::json AS r) TO STDOUT" >  ./relative_path/file.csv`

Comment: Note that the output in the file `file.json` is not JSON, rather, ever line in that file is a JSON object that represents a row. But the file altogether is not valid JSON, you would need to wrap the whole file in between `[` and `]` and add the needed commas at the end of lines.

Comment: Yes as mentioned above, because each line is a row, the final output is also called JSON line format (where each line is a valid JSON object). Anyway, most tools deal automatically with this format like `jq`.

Comment: Worth to mention that instead of doing first `\t` + _Enter_ and then `\a` + _Enter_ ... you can do all in one input: `\t\a\o file.json` + _Enter_

Answer (score 28):

Please find below **the only answer** that outputs **actually valid JSON** (i.e. array of objects).

```
\t
\a
\o data.json
select json_agg(t) FROM (SELECT * from table) t;
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006432/1456173))

Comment: Should be higher up. Thank you!

Comment: or directly from command line using flags here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467301/1098564, ```psql -d postgres -qAtX -c "select json_agg(t) FROM (SELECT * from table) t;" -o data.json```

Answer (score 9):

For me @Vérace's answer didn't maintain the column names, but assigned default names (`f1`, `f2`, etc.) instead. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 with the [JSON extension](https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91).

If you want to export the entire table, there is no need for a subquery. In addition, this **will** maintain the column names. I used the folowing query:

```
COPY (SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM fred as t) to '/home/pol/Downloads/software/postgres/inst/myfile';
```

Comment: It did maintain column names! `CREATE TABLE fred (mary INT, jimmy INT, paulie VARCHAR(20));` and the result: `{"mary":2,"jimmy":43,"paulie":"asfasfasfd"}` - field names are mary, jimmy, paulie... and **NOT** (`f1`, `f2`, etc.)...

Answer (score 9):

I will add a special caveat to [Verace's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90495/104304). **You need to do post processing on the outputted JSON file if you have text columns with backslash characters: `\`**.

Otherwise you will get duplicate (`\` -> `\\`) at best and completely invalid JSON at worse ie:

This:

```
{ "f1" : "crap\""}.
```

Becomes

```
{ "f1" : "crap\\""}.
```

Which looks fine but is completely invalid JSON.

You can replace the `\\` into `\` with sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' PG_OUT_JSON_FILE.json
```

From [Postgres COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) where they round about mention it:

> Presently, COPY TO will never emit an octal or hex-digits backslash
>   sequence, but it does use the other sequences listed above for those
>   control characters. Any other backslashed character that is not
>   mentioned in the above table will be taken to represent itself.
>   However, beware of adding backslashes unnecessarily, since that might
>   accidentally produce a string matching the end-of-data marker (.) or
>   the null string (\N by default). These strings will be recognized
>   before any other backslash processing is done.
>
> It is strongly recommended that applications generating COPY data
>   convert data newlines and carriage returns to the \n and \r sequences
>   respectively. At present it is possible to represent a data carriage
>   return by a backslash and carriage return, and to represent a data
>   newline by a backslash and newline. However, these representations
>   might not be accepted in future releases. They are also highly
>   vulnerable to corruption if the COPY file is transferred across
>   different machines (for example, from Unix to Windows or vice versa).
>
> COPY TO will terminate each row with a Unix-style newline ("\n").
>   Servers running on Microsoft Windows instead output carriage
>   return/newline ("\r\n"), but only for COPY to a server file; for
>   consistency across platforms, COPY TO STDOUT always sends "\n"
>   regardless of server platform. COPY FROM can handle lines ending with
>   newlines, carriage returns, or carriage return/newlines. To reduce the
>   risk of error due to un-backslashed newlines or carriage returns that
>   were meant as data, COPY FROM will complain if the line endings in the
>   input are not all alike.

Comment: I have dealt with this one in the answer - I hope you find it satisfactory. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite..) and free solution that you don't have to install any software for (except Docker), see https://github.com/function61/sql2json

Full disclosure: I wrote that software.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to achieve with [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql):

```
$ psql -U my_user -h my_host -c "SELECT * FROM my_users" --csv my_db | spyql "SELECT * FROM csv TO json"
{"id": 1, "name": "David"}
{"id": 2, "name": "James"}
{"id": 3, "name": "Joana"}
{"id": 4, "name": "Hellen"}
```

We are using psql to export a query/table to CSV and then spyql to convert the CSV to json lines.

For the record, I created a sample table with the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE my_users AS
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1, 'David'), (2, 'James'), (3, 'Joana'), (4, 'Hellen')) AS t(id, name);
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql

Answer (score 1):

Variant of @gunar-gessner 's answer with but with output file specified inline

```sql
\t
\a
select json_agg(t) FROM (SELECT * from table) t \g data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
PG_CONNECTION_STR="postgresql://username:password@postgresql-host:port/dbname"

dump_pg_query_json() {
    file_name=$1; sql=$2 ; shift 2;
    echo "SQL Query> ${sql}";
    echo "Output file> ${file_name}";
    psql -Atx ${PG_CONNECTION_STR} -c "COPY( SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t, TRUE) FROM ( ${sql} ) t ) TO STDOUT WITH NULL AS ''" > "${file_name}"
}
```