# How to query all rows of a table into single json Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to generate a single json by querying from a table with id as key and email as value like this

```
{1: "abc@example.com", 2: "abcd@example.com"}
```

My attempt to create is:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(id, email)) 
from auth_user 
where id in (4733, 3625, 4961, 4237);
```

which results me

```
[{4733: "abc@example.com"}, {3625: "abcd@example.com"}]
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) not `json_agg`

Comment: @BalasubramanianRaju you probably also want jsonb, not not json

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could try my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90495/34007) - be careful of the caveats after the answer itself - esp. with respect to \ (backslashes).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I was looking for json_object_agg only and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating a comment to an answer.

> I think you are looking for json_object_agg not json_agg – a_horse_with_no_name 2 hours ago

Links

- [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)