# MySQL: Return JSON from a standard SQL Query

Tags: mysql, json

I have read about JSON objects and the JSON object type.  I only want to do a select and it return JSON.  I do not necessarily want to store a JSON object.  Serialization per se it not my question.  The columns are regular Varchar, Int, etc. columns, no JSON Objects, "normal" database rows.

Can I do a regular old SELECT and return JSON for MySQL?

Isn't this what [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) in SQL SERVER and [rows_for_json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) do in PostgreSQL?

They seemed ahead in this are but I didn't want to fool myself.

I found this question from 2016:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324795/mysql-5-7-return-row-as-json-using-new-json-features

Comment: there is no rows_for_json in postgresql

Comment: What about row_to_json?  Maybe that's what I meant.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169658/199364,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760134/199364, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35957518/199364,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Took a bit of figuring out (more used to PostgreSQL where things are [**much** easier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/export-postgres-table-as-json/90495#90495)!), but if you consult the fine manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html), under `12.16.2 Functions That Create JSON Values`, there's the `JSON_ARRAY` function, but it's not much use really - at least in this case!

To answer the question `"select and it return JSON"`, there are two ways of doing this, both rather painful!

You can either

- use a "hack" - see the db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/37ru5oq4dFQSscwYsfx386/1),
- **or** use one of the new MySQL supplied JSON functions here - which, ironically, appears to be even more of a hack than the hack itself! Only with MySQL! :-) (fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEz4mZX56Jj7TWRsN91ibX/4)).

Both answers use the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` function - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276949/470530) helped. You might want to set the [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable to a bit more than its default (a paltry 1024)!

The first query is, as you can imagine, messy (`DDL` and `DML` at the bottom of this answer):

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', better_result, ']') AS best_result FROM
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('{', my_json, '}' SEPARATOR ',') AS better_result FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
      '"name_field":'   , '"', name_field   , '"', ',' 
      '"address_field":', '"', address_field, '"', ','
      '"contact_age":'  , contact_age
    ) AS my_json
  FROM contact
) AS more_json
) AS yet_more_json;
```

Result:

```
[{"name_field":"Mary","address_field":"address one","contact_age":25},{"name_field":"Fred","address_field":"address two","contact_age":35},{"name_field":"Bill","address_field":"address three","contact_age":47}]
```

which is correct, but, let's face it, a bit of a nightmare!

Then there's the MySQL `JSON_ARRAY()` approach (which is even messier - thanks MySQL for your (non-existent) implementation of the `TRANSLATE()` function!).

```
SELECT
CONCAT
('[', REPLACE
  (
    REPLACE
    (
      GROUP_CONCAT
      (
        JSON_ARRAY
        (
          'name_field:', name_field, 
          'address_field:', address_field, 
          'age_field:', contact_age
        ) SEPARATOR ','
      ), '[', '{'
    ), ']', '}'
  ), ']'
) 
AS best_result2 
FROM contact
```

Same result!

```
====  TABLE CREATION and INSERT DDL and DML ============

    CREATE TABLE contact
    (
         name_field VARCHAR  (5) NOT NULL,
      address_field VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
      contact_age   INTEGER      NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO contact
    VALUES
    ('Mary', 'address one',   25),
    ('Fred', 'address two',   35),
    ('Bill', 'address three', 47);
```

Answer (score 26):

## Converting a row to json

It doesn't sound to me like you want to aggregate JSON. You state you want the equivalent of `row_to_json`, if so then I suggest checking out the much simpler [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html)

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'name_field', name_field,
  'address_field', address_field,
  'contact_age', contact_age
)
FROM contact;
```

## Aggregating JSON

As a side note, if you do need to aggregate a resultset to json. then the upcoming MySQL 8 will do that for you.

- [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)    Return result set as a single JSON array
- [`JSON_OBJECTAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)`   Return result set as a single JSON object

Comment: Looks like the JSON AGG functions are also available in 5.7.22+
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg

Comment: When I execute following SELECT JSON_OBJECT("key",col1); it give syntax error. But if we use SELECT JSON_OBJECT("key":col1); it works.

Answer (score 12):

For an array of JSON objects (one object per row in query), you can do this:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("fieldA", fieldA, "fieldB", fieldB)) 
  FROM table;
```

It would result in a single JSON array containing all entries:

```
[
  {
    "fieldA": "value",
    "fieldB": "value"
  },
  ...
]
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow for selecting all fields with `*`. This would be awesome, but does **not** work:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) FROM table;
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION database.JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist

Comment: This is for MySQL 8.0 only. Documentation is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what I needed, much simpler this way!

Answer (score 6):

This will give you the same answer, but a lot easier code. I just used `json_object` with `group_concat` to simplify the [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192239).

```
select 
    concat('[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(    
                'name_field', name_field
                ,'address_field', address_field
                ,'contact_age', contact_age
                )
            SEPARATOR ',')
    ,']')
    from contact;
```

Comment: This is good answer!

Comment: How we can then parse into php, any short cut methods? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to do this in the context of any particular host environment (e.g. node.js, Python, MySQL Workbench), then [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/) supports [JSON output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-json-output.html). Each row in a result is output as a separate object. It can pretty-print output, and can output an array of objects or separate each row with newlines. For example, from the shell prompt, type:

```
\option resultFormat json/array
```

Then run a query as normal.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts;
```

As a bonus, MySQL Shell also supports JavaScript and Python, though you can only get away from SQL statements if the server is set up as a [document store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html). Then, once you've set the active schema, you can access relational tables via the `db` object. Whether using JS or Python, the statement corresponding to the above SQL query is the same:

```
\use people
db.contacts.find()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seconding @outis's answer. Using the mysql shell is the most straight forward solution to return rows as JSON from a sql formatted query.

You can specify the --result-format and the --sql parameters on the shell invocation to specify the result format as json and to use sql to interface with the server, like so:

```
mysqlsh -u {user} --result-format=json --sql
```

Then run whatever sql queries you desire and the result output will be in JSON format.  Here's an example creating a JSON test db, table, insertion, and select:

```
     SQL > create database jsonTest;
     SQL > use jsonTest;
     SQL > create table JsonTest (field1 int default -1, field2 varchar(32) default '');
     SQL > insert into JsonTest (field1, field2) values (1, "My JSON test");
     SQL > select * from JsonTest;
      {
       "field1": 1,
       "field2": "My JSON test"
      }
      1 row in set (0.0032 sec)
```