# Is there a way to let MySQL join some external data without importing those data into DB?

Tags: mysql, join

I have some static data which stored in a JSON file:

```
outinfo=
[{out_id:123,out_name:'hello'}]
```

and I have a table:

```
----tableA----  
| id | label | out_id |  
| 1  |   a   |   123  |
| 2  |   b   |   123  |
```

I wanna select all info out like

```
{id:1,label:"a",out_name:"hello"}
```

It is easy to achieve that by importing the outside JSON data into DB table, and select them out through a simple `left join` query. 
But I wanna know how to achieve that if I don't create a table for those static data.

Comment: No way. And no reasons for NOT import, especially when the data is static.

Comment: You'll have to write a programme to do stuff like  that!

Comment: yes,i was always vacillate in these little decitions. more left join always make me think things come more complex. but if i select the origin data out, then enhance them with other json data by outside program, the complex is apparent. so,i keep them in db at last.

Comment: This may be part of it:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query