# Sql subquery for nested parent child data

Tags: mysql, subquery, hierarchy, concat

I have two tables , on parent table (categories ) and child table (features).. I have this query

```
    select c.* , 
            (select GROUP_CONCAT(f.featuresId , f.featuresTitle ) 
            from applika.features f  
            where f.categoriesId = c.categoriesId 
            group by categoriesId) as nestedData 
        from applika.categories c
```

**PROBLEM** : but in nestedData column my subquery in group_concat show the result inside quotes like this :

```
 "nestedData": "featuresId:1featuresTitle:title1 ,featuresId:2featuresTitle:title2 ,featuresId:3featuresTitle:title3 ,featuresId:4featuresTitle:4"
```

**REQUEST** :  but I don't want to show data in **quotes** , is there another way instead of GROUP_CONCAT or CONCAT to select my child data in ordinary array of objects like this for example :

```
    [
        ...

 "nestedData": [
          {"featuresId":1 , "featuresTitle":"title1"},
          {"featuresId":2 , "featuresTitle":"title2"} ,
          {"featuresId":3 , "featuresTitle":"title3"},
          {"featuresId":4 , "featuresTitle":title4"}
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be JSON? Take a look at this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query

Comment: MySQL never adds quotes until you ask for it directly (for example, by using JSON function). So I see three variants. 1) Quotes already exists in source data. 2) Quotes are added by your client software. 3) `applika.features` is a view which uses some JSON function. Variant 2 is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('featuresId', f.featuresId, 'featuresTitle', f.featuresTitle)) AS nestedData
FROM
    applika.categories c
LEFT JOIN
    applika.features f
    ON f.categoriesId = c.categoriesId
GROUP BY
    c.categoriesId;
```